# Adding a <Img> tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Originally, my image container div was:

```
<div id="offer_image" class="img_preview_container" />
<a class="preview_overlay"></a>
</div>
```

Then this executed:

```
$('#image_upload_form input').change(function() {

    if ( $(this).val() == '') return false;

    $('#image_upload_form').ajaxSubmit({
        success: function ( data ) { 
            if ( (/^http:\/\//).test(data) ) {
                $('#offer_detail input[name=image]').val(data);
                myImage = new Image();
                myImage.src = data;
                $(myImage).load(function() {
                    $('#offer_image').updateimgto(myImage.src);
                });
            }
            else {
                $('<div></div>').html(data).dialog({ title: 'Unable to upload your image' });
            }
        },
    });

});
```

When that JavaScript code executed, an `<img>` tag is added to the orignal image container div:

```
<div id="offer_image" class="img_preview_container" />
    <a class="preview_overlay"></a>
    <img src="http://www.test.com/pic1.png", alt="uploaded img">
</div>
```

I am not sure where exactly the tag `<img>` is being added. Is it:

1. `$('#offer_image').updateimgto(myImage.src)`?
2. I put `myImage.title="my pic"` in the JavaScript but it doesn't add to that `<img>` tag output. Why?

Comment: What's `updateimgto` defined as?

Comment: note <div id="offer_image" class="img_preview_container" />
should be <div id="offer_image" class="img_preview_container"> as what you have there is invalid HTML

Answer (score 1):

1. Most likely in the `updateimgto` function, would need to see it to be sure.
2. After the call to `updateimgto` try adding 
   `$('#offer_image img').attr('title','my pic');` 
    
   This should help clarify if the image has been added to the DOM at this point and also update the title.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place

```
<div id="offer_image" class="img_preview_container" /> //
```

needs to be

```
<div id="offer_image" class="img_preview_container" >
```

Secondly what does 
this  `$('#offer_image').updateimgto(myImage.src);`

Is updateimgto  a method of some particular plugin.. If not why are you calling like a method for an object ??